# ListBox selected item inherits all the data before it

Tags: c#

Masters! Please help me with my problem. I have a listbox and a datagridview. In the first item in the listbox let say `index=0`, whenever I added an item to the Datagridview and update, it returns the correct value but when I go to the second item in the list and add a item to the database all the items before the selected get inherited but not in the database it's in the form. 
Example:
I have 3 Items in the `listbox` (One, Two and Three). Now if edit the values in the datagridview list then save in the database it is successfully saved. But in the form It doesn't change. The strange thing is when I click on Item "`One`" and "`Three`" the items in the datagridview doesn't change. It seems  like it freezes..Is there a way to get problem corrected?I was able to make a solution which is this one:

```
    FrmMain.ActiveForm.Dispose();
    FrmMain frm = new FrmMain();
    frm.ShowDialog();
```

The problem with this one is it reloads the form. I want only the listbox to reload or refresh. I've done already refresh and invalidate but no help.

Comment: What is it you are actually trying to accomplish?
In this case I wouldn't dispose the form at all but I would simply make a reload function so it loads the data again from the database.

Comment: I want to add the data in the database and after I click the button save it should save the data which is in my case it is working but when i click on the other item, the data in the datagridview is not changing to its corresponding data. For example if i changed the data in listbox item "Two" D = 1 and when I click on the listbox item "One", the value in listbox Two is inherited.

Comment: I think it freezes. If I have 5 items in listbox and updated the last item then all the items 4,3,2,1 in the listbox inherits all the data of item 5 but in the database the data are all correct. The problem is in the form only

Comment: use the debugger. I guess you use Visual Studio so use the debugger. Set breakpoints at certain points to find out where its freezing.

Comment: Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx